# Can't install Python Packages via Python SSH

Tags: raspbian, python, raspbian-jessie

I'm running Raspbian Jesse on my Raspberry Pi and I get [the following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyaMK.png):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

I have OpenSSL 1.1.1i (Dec 8, 2020 ver) and Python 3.9.1 installed. Not sure what's going wrong here. Any help?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie is deprecated and out of support since one year and its repository is archived. I'm afraid you will not find someone who remember the old installation to help you, in particular with latest versions from now. I strongly recommend to use an up to date Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: I thought that was the case but was hoping for otherwise. In any case, thanks! I'll wipe the SD card and install some other OS.